# Algorithm for converting octal numbers to decimal?

Tags: python, decimal, converters, octal

I have a list of octal numbers that I want to be converted to decimal. Here's my class with what I've done so far:

```
class Octal:

    #Reads in the file into numberList, converting each line into an int.
    def __init__(self):
        list = []
        file = open("Number Lists/random_numbers3.txt")
        for line in file:
            list.append(int(line))
        self.numberList = list
        file.close()

    #Convert numberList to decimal
    def dec_convert(self):
        decimal = 0
        decimalList = []
        for line in self.numberList:
            temp = str(line)
            i = 0
            while i < len(temp):
                digit = int(temp[i])
                item = (digit * (8 ** (len(temp) - i)))
                decimal = decimal + item
                i += 1

            decimalList.append(decimal)
        return decimalList



    def get_list(self):
        return self.numberList
```

I read in the numbers from a file, that works fine. But I don't think that my dec_convert() function actually works. It just keeps running and doesn't finish.

It looks completely terrible and hard to read, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way of converting each octal number in the list to a decimal number?

Comment: Can't you just use `int(num_str, base)` to do the conversion?  For instance, `int("23", 8)` returns 19, which is the string "23" interpreted as octal.

Comment: Where do you increment `i` inside the `while` loop??? No wonder "it keeps running".

Comment: @TomKarzes, doesn't that convert from decimal to octal? I need octal to decimal.

Comment: @ScottieJoe: no it *parses* the string to an int with the given base, as the [specs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) say.

Comment: To be clear, your `dec_convert` doesn't conver to decimal either. It converts from an octal `str` to an `int`, precisely what `int(line,8)` would do.

Comment: @ScottieJoe It converts a string in any base into a native integer, which is exactly what you want.  Didn't you even look at the example I included?  How could you possibly not have understood it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy solution that uses the built-in `int()` constructor rather your `dec_convert()` function.

```
class Octal:
    def __init__(self):
        with open("Number Lists/random_numbers3.txt") as fp:
            self.numberList = map(lambda x:int(x,8), fp)
    def get_list(self):
        return self.numberList

if __name__=="__main__":
    o = Octal()
    print(o.get_list())
```

Comment: But doesn't that "int(x,8)" convert it to octal? I need it FROM octal TO decimal.

Comment: No, that `int(x,8)` converts FROM octal TO `int`. Try this experiment to see how it works: `print(int('20',8))`. You should see that the octal string `'20'` is converted to an int with a value of 16.

Comment: I see, so would that convert something like (octal)7777 to (dec)4095?

Comment: No, it would convert (octal)'7777' to an int, the value of which is (decimal)4095. If you want to convert to the decimal string representation, you need one more step: `str(int('7777',8))` would convert (octal)'7777' to (decimal)'4095'.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use *list comprehension*:

```
def dec_convert(self):
    decimalList = [self._convert_to_dec(line) for line in self.numberList]
```

and with:

```
def _convert_to_dec(self,dec) :
    n = len(temp)-1
    return sum(int(x)*(8**(n-i)) for i,x in enumerate(dec))
```

The first code fragment is a simple list comprehension that calls `self._convert_to_dec` on *all elements in `self.numberList*. Not much magic there.

The `_convert_to_dec` is more complicated: we first calculate the amount of digits and store it in `n`. Next we define a generator that [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)s over the characters and binds `i` to the corresponding index. The generator multiplies each element with the corresponding power of `8` and the digit. This is a generator, so no real list is constructed.

By running this through [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) we obtain the sum which is the requested result.

Or as [@TomKarzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394609/algorithm-for-converting-octal-numbers-to-decimal/36394668#comment60405789_36394609) says, you can use [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) with a given base (in this case `8`.